# Spring Batch how to process list of data before write in a Step

Tags: java, spring, batch-processing, spring-batch

I am trying to read client data from database and write processed data to a flat file.
But I need to process whole result of the `ItemReader` before write data.

For example, I am reading Client from database rows :

```
public class Client {
    private String id;
    private String subscriptionCode;
    private Boolean activated;
}
```

But I want to count and write how many user are activated grouped by subscriptionCode :

```
public class Subscription {
    private String subscriptionCode;
    private Integer activatedUserCount;
}
```

I don't know how to perform that using `ItemReader`/`ItemProcessor`/`ItemWriter`, can you help me ?

BatchConfiguration :

```
@CommonsLog
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class BatchConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Bean
    public Step step1() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                .<Client, Client> chunk(1000)
                .reader(new ListItemReader<Client>(new ArrayList<Client>() { // Just for test
                    {
                        add(Client.builder().id("1").subscriptionCode("AA").activated(true).build());
                        add(Client.builder().id("2").subscriptionCode("BB").activated(true).build());
                        add(Client.builder().id("3").subscriptionCode("AA").activated(false).build());
                        add(Client.builder().id("4").subscriptionCode("AA").activated(true).build());
                    }
                }))
                .processor(new ItemProcessor<Client, Client>() {
                    public Client process(Client item) throws Exception {
                        log.info(item);
                        return item;
                    }
                })
                .writer(new ItemWriter<Client>() {
                    public void write(List<? extends Client> items) throws Exception {
                        // Only here I can use List of Client
                        // How can I process this list before to fill Subscription objects ?
                    }
                })
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job job1(Step step1) throws Exception {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("job1").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer()).start(step1).build();
    }
}
```

Main application:

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException, JobRestartException, JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException, JobParametersInvalidException {
        System.exit(SpringApplication.exit(SpringApplication.run(BatchConfiguration.class, args)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question completely, you do have the `ItemProcessor` right..you can do any processing that you want on individual `Client` instances there - is there something other than this processing that you intend to perform?

Comment: I want to count how many user have `activated` flag set to `true` grouped by subscriptionCode. So I need to have a `Client` List to determine my `Subscription` List. But using `chunk`, I can only process row by row... not a group. The result attempt to a writer should be a List of 2 subscription in this example : `Subscription(subscriptionCode=AA, activatedUserCount=2)` and `Subscription(subscriptionCode=BB, activatedUserCount=1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution based on `ItemProcessor` :

```
@Bean
public Step step1() {
  return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
      .<Client, Subscription> chunk(1000)
      .reader(new ListItemReader<Client>(new ArrayList<Client>() {
        {
          add(Client.builder().id("1").subscriptionCode("AA").activated(true).build());
          add(Client.builder().id("2").subscriptionCode("BB").activated(true).build());
          add(Client.builder().id("3").subscriptionCode("AA").activated(false).build());
          add(Client.builder().id("4").subscriptionCode("AA").activated(true).build());
        }
      }))
      .processor(new ItemProcessor<Client, Subscription>() {
        private List<Subscription> subscriptions;

        public Subscription process(Client item) throws Exception {
          for (Subscription s : subscriptions) { // try to retrieve existing element
            if (s.getSubscriptionCode().equals(item.getSubscriptionCode())) { // element found
              if(item.getActivated()) {
                s.getActivatedUserCount().incrementAndGet(); // increment user count
                log.info("Incremented subscription : " + s);
              }                             
              return null; // existing element -> skip
            }
          }
          // Create new Subscription
          Subscription subscription = Subscription.builder().subscriptionCode(item.getSubscriptionCode()).activatedUserCount(new AtomicInteger(1)).build();
          subscriptions.add(subscription);
          log.info("New subscription : " + subscription);
          return subscription;
        }

        @BeforeStep
        public void initList() {
          subscriptions = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Subscription>());
        }

        @AfterStep
        public void clearList() {
          subscriptions.clear();
        }
      })
      .writer(new ItemWriter<Subscription>() {                  
        public void write(List<? extends Subscription> items) throws Exception {
          log.info(items);
          // do write stuff
        }                   
      })
      .build();
}
```

But I have to maintain a second `Subscription` List into `ItemProcessor` (I don't know if is thread safe and efficient ?). What do you think about this solution ?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand from your comments you need to make a summary of activated account, right?
You can create a `Subscription` for every `Client` you are processing and with a [`ItemWriterLister.afterWrite`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/ItemWriteListener.html#afterWrite-java.util.List-) write the above created `Subscription`s items to database.

Comment: These are just listeners on objects defined by the chunk. But how can I pass a `List<Subscription>` to my `ItemWriter` to be processed ?
I cannot declare `.<Client, Subscription> chunk(1000)` because one `Client` cannot be transformed in one `Subscription` (chunk process item by item)...

Comment: Using a listener to write something is not conventional... Furthermore, ItemWriter write method always give me access to a List a Client. But you give me an idea : using `ItemProcessor` (see my anwser)