# Spring Batch how to filter duplicated items before send it to ItemWriter

Tags: spring, batch-processing, spring-batch

I read a flat file (for example a .csv file with 1 line per User, Ex: *UserId;Data1;Date2*).

But how to handle duplicated User item in the reader (where is no list of previus readed users...)

```
stepBuilderFactory.get("createUserStep1")
.<User, User>chunk(1000)
.reader(flatFileItemReader) // FlatFileItemReader
.writer(itemWriter) // For example JDBC Writer
.build();
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Filtering is typically done with an `ItemProcessor`.  If the `ItemProcessor` returns null, the item is filtered and not passed to the `ItemWriter`.  Otherwise, it is.  In your case, you could keep a list of previously seen users in the `ItemProcessor`.  If the user hasn't been seen before, pass it on.  If it has been seen before, return null.  You can read more about filtering with an `ItemProcessor` in the documentation here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/processor.html#filteringRecords

```
/**
* This implementation assumes that there is enough room in memory to store the duplicate
* Users.  Otherwise, you'd want to store them somewhere you can do a look-up on.
*/
public class UserFilterItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor<User, User> {

    // This assumes that User.equals() identifies the duplicates
    private Set<User> seenUsers = new HashSet<User>();

    public User process(User user) {
        if(seenUsers.contains(user)) {
            return null;
        }
        seenUsers.add(user);
        return user;
        
    }
}
```

Comment: After fetching my last questions on stackoverflow, I found my solution (what you say) : http://stackoverflow.com/a/26318180/1121571
Is this the best solution (keep a list in item processor) because a list I passed to ItemWriter, so where it is stored internally ? How can I access to it properly ?

Comment: This would be custom `ItemProcessor` implementation so it's up to you where to store the previously seen users.

Comment: How to keep the last entry ?

Comment: How can I reset the Set? Wont it lead to memory leaks? @MichaelMinella

Comment: @BlancaHdez You can use a listener or implement the `ItemStream` interface and reset the `Set` in the `close` method.

Answer (score 6):

As you could see here http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html#faultTolerant

> When a chunk is rolled back, items that have been cached during reading may be reprocessed. If a step is configured to be fault tolerant (uses skip or retry processing typically), any ItemProcessor used should be implemented in a way that is idempotent

This means that in Michael's example, the first time a user is *Processed* the user is cached in the Set and if there is a failure *Writing* the item, if the step is fault tolerance the *Processor* will be executed again for the same User and this *Filter* will filter out the user.

Improved code:

```
/**
 * This implementation assumes that there is enough room in memory to store the duplicate
 * Users.  Otherwise, you'd want to store them somewhere you can do a look-up on.
 */
public class UserFilterItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor<User, User> {

    // This assumes that User.equals() identifies the duplicates
    private Set<User> seenUsers = new HashSet<User>();

    public User process(User user) {
        if(seenUsers.contains(user) && !user.hasBeenProcessed()) {
            return null;
        } else {
            seenUsers.add(user);
            user.setProcessed(true);
            return user;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite the `equals()` and `hashcode()` method of `User`, then you can delete the "contains" codition.