# Spring Batch how to remove duplicate items in processor where last entry have preference before send to item writer

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I read a flat file (for example a .csv file with 1 line per User, Ex: UserId,age,rate,marks).
Below is example

```
user1,27,good,1111111
user2,56,fair,222222
user1,28,good,333333
```

So as per above data Item processor should pass user object at row 2 & row 3 to item writer.
But how to handle duplicated User item in the item processor (where last entry of duplicate user given precedence or should be pass to itemwriter)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Batch how to filter duplicated items before send it to ItemWriter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27318466/spring-batch-how-to-filter-duplicated-items-before-send-it-to-itemwriter)

Comment: Actually this query is different want to remove first duplicate entry and keep last entry

Comment: Logic is the same. You can have a set and check whether it contains user (if yes just replace)

Comment: With that logic I will get row1 & row2 in item writer but I want row 2 & row 3   in item writer

Comment: Is user1/user2 a key in the data?  Would it be possible to use a Map and overwrite based on the key?

Comment: Yes user1/user2 is key, but by using the Map how can I make sure only row2 & row3 get a pass to the writer ?

Comment: Any suggestion on this?Should I create another step to achieve it