# Spring Batch - Item Writer to update an item/record

Tags: spring

I am working on a spring batch application where I read from a stored procedure from database and write it to an xml file.

My writer is a org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemWriter

I am trying to implement a situation in which I find duplicates using this method - [Spring Batch how to filter duplicated items before send it to ItemWriter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27318466/spring-batch-how-to-filter-duplicated-items-before-send-it-to-itemwriter/27319419?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

However, in my situation I don't want to skip a duplicate but override an existing record written to XML by my ItemWriter.

How can I achieve it ?

Comment: parse xml => replace node